# Flex DataGrid labelFunction not getting called

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, labelfunction

I have a DataGrid where one of the columns has a labelFunction.  When I run the application a scrollbar shows up in the DataGrid indicating to me that it has data but there is nothing in the DataGrid.  When I scroll items start showing up.  When I Debugged it I noticed that the labelFunction was never being called until I started scrolling.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: did you use validateNow() after you assign the dataprovider?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample? How are you setting the labelFunction?  In MXML?

Comment: which of the two functions did the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are assigning `labelFunction` at a later time using ActionScript after setting the `dataProvider`, try calling [datagrid.invalidateList()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#invalidateList%28%29) or [datagrid.updateList()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#updateList%28%29) after assigning it - these functions force a refresh of all the rows.